# Sending and Retrieving Form data with Node Js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have already created two js files each of which sends and returns form data to/from the database. My question is if its better/possible to leave the two Js files as is and to serve the individual functions or if its better practice to combine them into a singular Js file. The two POST requests are like so for clarity.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile('existing.html', { root:__dirname});
});
```

//Node.js body parseing middleware; used for req.body

```
app.post('/submit',urlencodedParser,function (req, res){
connection.connect(function (err) {
console.log(req.body.lname);
var lname = req.body.lname;

var sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE lname= '" + lname + "'";
connection.query(sql, function(err,result,rows) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Nerfbutton and welcome to SO. Please read How to ask, maybe take the tour. You'll discover this isn't a code writing service. Everyone will be glad to help if you come here with code you've written to solve your problem - but need some help to get it working

Comment: ive already written the two programs, i wasnt trying to ask on how to do it but what would be better practice to do

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you need help regarding better way of organizing your Express.js code and routers.
If I am not wrong then following tutorials will help you in that.

1. An Intuitive Way To Organize Your ExpressJS Routes
   http://www.codetunnel.io/an-intuitive-way-to-organize-your-expressjs-routes/
2. Quick Tip: Organizing Routes in Large Express 4.x Apps
   https://start.jcolemorrison.com/quick-tip-organizing-routes-in-large-express-4-x-apps/

Thanks,
Jignesh Raval